# Google Sheets formula to Extract part of a string

Tags: google-sheets

I am in a pickle and need some help extracting portion of a string in a google sheet cell.

SM - Lead - LINE ITEM GOES HERE (ABC) - Jan $ 11.75 3,515.00 $ 41,301.25

I am looking to extract the amount after the second dollar ($) sign.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the spaces and the format will be the same, you can try the formula below:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"\$ \S+ \S+ \$ (\S+)")
```

This resulted to:
[image]

Comment: This worked! Can you walk me through the formula so I can adapt it? I am not very familiar with Regextract. Thanks!

Comment: REGEXEXTRACT() is used to extract specific words/characters from a string by using regular expression(regex). You can refer here for the documentation about it. https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en
Also, I'll appreciate it if you will upvote/accept the answer that solves your problem so that other users will know what the solution is if they encounter this. https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I just did but I do not have a +15 reputation to show :)

Comment: Accepting an answer doesn't need any reputation from the author of the post. :) You can read the link I commented above for guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the second dollar sign is always at the end of the string, you can also try

```
=regexextract(A2, "[^$\s]+$")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. When I tried this formula in my sheet, I got the 3,515.00 amount... which is different than what you had... I am not very familiar with Regextract, can you walk me through the your formula?

Comment: For an example with explanation see: https://regex101.com/r/bYl89n/1